# Possessive pronoun

Tags: grammar, possessives, apostrophe

The Emptiness will always be my favourite Alesana's album.

The Emptiness will always be my favourite Alesana album.

which one is correct? as to my understanding that people would not use the possessive " 's " when referring to albums eg. "Where did you get that Linkin Park album?"

Comment: No apostrophe on attributive nouns, but bands named *(The) XXXs* do well: *Animals, B-52s, Backsteet Boys, Bangles, Beach Boys, Beatles, Bee Gees,
Byrds, Cadillacs, Cars, Cranberries, Dire Straights, Dominoes, Doors,
Drifters, Eagles, Eurythmics, Everly Brothers, Flamingos, Guns and Roses,
Gypsy Kings, Hollies, Kinks, Monkeys, Nine Inch Nails, Penguins, Pet Shop
Boys, Pixies, Platters, Pointer Sisters, Pretenders, Ramones, Rolling
Stones, Scorpions, Smashing Pumpkins, Sonics, Stooges, Supremes, Talking
Heads, Tempations, Travelling Wilburys, Turtles, Yardbirds* — just to name some recent ones.

Comment: @tchrist: Not sure if you downvoted my answer, but the question was not about using possessives for band names ending in "s"

Comment: @TwoSheds Nope, not me.

Answer (score 2):

Your second example is correct: *The Emptiness will always be my favourite Alesana album.*

You would not use a possessive without a preceeding "of" : *The Emptiness will always be my favourite **of** Alesana's albums.*

This is not limited to speaking of musical albums, by any means. Equally, you would not say "*Pride and Prejudice will always be my favorite Jane Austin's book*," or "*Starry Night is my favorite Van Gogh's painting*."